# How to find a match between specific columns?

Tags: string, search, vim, substring

Example line 7 in a textfile:

```
This is an example
```

This is my search code:

```
/example\|an
```

Now I want to capture the matches in a substring from column 1 to column 11:

```
let myhits = [] | 7s/\%>0cexample\|an\%<12c/\=add(myhits,submatch(0))[-1]/ge | echo myhits
```

I expected:

```
myhits = ["an"]
```

but found:

```
myhits = ["an", "example"]
```

What did I wrong?
How can I capture a match in a substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything separated by `\|` is its own branch, so that in your expression the left branch doesn't check the end column and the right branch doesn't check the end column. You can use grouping to only branch on the keywords: `\%>0c\(example\|an\)\%<12c`.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately not always is it possible in my case to group my search. Would it be a solution to capture the substring and do a search afterwards only in the substring?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea. You can use `let myLine = getline(7)[0:10]` and then write something similar to the pseudocode `while (length(myLine) > 0) {call substitute(pattern, "", myLine) for each pattern and add to myhits if myLine changed}`. I can't come up with the vim syntax off the top of my head, but `help function-list` or `help substitute` might help.